# Animate buttons by looping over an array

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, animation

I am making a simple 'Simon Says' style app in Swift and I would like to flash buttons to show the sequence the user has to follow.

I have made this function which iterates over an array of the buttons to just change the background colour for now.

```
func animateButtons() {
        for (index, button) in buttonSequence.enumerated() {
            UIButton.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: TimeInterval(index)) {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 63/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 168/255, green: 61/255, blue: 164/255, alpha: 0.85)
            }
        }
    }
```

Right now though when the function is called it lights up all the buttons at once but animates them returning back to their normal colour one by one. Ideally I want it to animate one button completely, then the next etc.

I looked into using a Timer for this but couldn't find exactly how to use it properly when searching documentation.

Comment: Your animation block sets 2 different colors. The first color will be ignored, and only the 2nd color will have any effect. What do you want your code to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you set the button color to 2 different values inside your animation block. The first color will be overridden and have no effect.

If you want each button to change to the first color in your animation block, hold for 1 second, and then revert to the 2nd color, change your code like this:

```
func animateButtons() {
        for (index, button) in buttonSequence.enumerated() {
            UIButton.animate(
              withDuration: 1, 
              delay: TimeInterval(index),
              animations: {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 63/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
               },
              completion: { finished in
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 168/255, green: 61/255, blue: 164/255, alpha: 0.85)
              }
            )
        }
}
```

Comment: (There is almost certainly at least 1 syntax error in the above code. It's only intended as a guide and you will need to clean it up.)

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to be working correctly now!

Comment: Do you know why once a button is in the array more than once it skips the animation for both instances?